# True of false: If $0<x<1$, then HCF of $x^4, x^5, x^6$ is $x^6$. Justify.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

True of false: If $0<x<1$, then HCF of $x^4, x^5, x^6$ is $x^6$. Justify.

I think it is true as $0<x<1$, $x^6$ is the minimum and hence a HCF. Please give me a proper justification.

Comment: This is not clear.  If you mean those as just three real numbers...well, there really isn't a notion of the highest common factor of two real numbers.  What would be the hcf of $\sqrt 2, \pi$, say?  If you mean them as polynomials then $x^4$ would be it.

Comment: x$^6$ is the SCM.

Comment: if you mean those values as polynomials, then the condition $0<x<1$ is redundant. If you mean those numerical values, then there's no notion of HCF for real numbers. Either way, I'm moved to wonder where this question came from.